# metodo GET en Express retorna vacio

Tags: javascript

La respuesta es vacia pienso que en Express estoy fallando porque el codigo en PHP funcione bien .

---

**Javascript (cliente)**

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

let btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btnEnviar');
btnEnviar.addEventListener("click", async function(e){

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', 'branch');

    var myRequest = new Request("./api", {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    });

    try {
        let response = await fetch(myRequest);
        let myData = await response.json();
        console.log(myData);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    }
});
```

---

**Código en NodeJs**

```js
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let server = require("http").Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);
let fs = require('fs');
let ejs = require("ejs");



app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use('/assets', 
express.static('assets'));


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/api", function(req, res, next){
  res.send(req.body);
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("SERVIDOR CORRIENDO PUERTO 3000");
});
```

Comment: Intenta en el `Request ("api/")` en vez de `Request ("./api")`

Comment: deberias abrir la consola y ver el error que te arroja

Comment: RETORNA EXITO EN LA PROMESA Y UN OBJETO VACIO EN LA RESPUESTA: Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} {}